# How to use a GAM to predict the probability in binomial data as a function of predictors

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, predictive-models, generalized-additive-model

I'd like to predict the probability of success as an unknown function of predictor variables. For example, consider the following fake data

```
#simulate fake data
n=100
x1 = runif(n)/2
x2 = runif(n)/2
ptrue = x1^1.4 + x2
trials = rpois(n,100)
successes = rbinom(n, prob = ptrue, size = trials)
data = data.frame(successes, trials, x1,x2)
```

I would like to fit a GAM with a binomial link (as the functional form of the predictors is unknown and likely quite nonlinear), but I can't figure out how to incorporate the known number of trials. Based on my reading of GAMs one might be able to do something like this in R

```
mod <- gam(successes/trials ~ x1  + x2, data = data, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

But that doesn't factor in the number of trials into the fitting. I've tried to google examples of GAMs in R like this, but I haven't had much luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is documented in `?glm`. One way to specify a binomial GLM is to pass it a matrix of successes and failures:

```r
gam(cbind(successes, trials - successes) ~ s(x1) + s(x2), data = data,
    method = "REML", family = binomial("logit"))
```

You can also proceed as you did but provide the number of trials via the `weights` arguments as in

```r
gam(successes/trials ~ s(x1) + s(x2), data = data,
    method = "REML", family = binomial("logit"),
    weights = trials)
```

And there is also the option of creating a factor variable indicating success or failure (be sure to code the first level as the failures).

For more see the *Details* section of `?glm`.

If you want to fit a GAM, you want smooth functions of the covariates; your model just included parametric terms. Be sure to use the `s()` or `te()` functions to indicate which covariates should be represented by penalised spline terms.

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't think to check the glm documentation, just the gam documentation. Ah yes, I missed the s() in my reproducible example (it is indeed in my real code).