# I need to correct a GAM model for sampling effort, any help?

Tags: r, biostatistics, generalized-additive-model

I created a GAM model to show the migration phenology of two species of birds in a region. I used detections (counts) as the response variable and week of the year as the predictor variable. The resulting GAM model is as follow:

[image]

Anyway, the model shows a reasonable curve shape, where the bird is absent during the austral winter, and present during the austral summer (from weeks 37 to 15).

But I have to correct this shape by sampling effort, i.e. not only include detections per week but also non-detections. I do have these data, but I don't know how to include them in this model. Should I calculate a proportion (detections/total samplings) and include such proportion as the response variable?

Here is the code I used in R to fit the model:

```r
model <- gam(
  bird_count ~ s(week, bs = "cc", k = 5), 
  family = nb(), 
  data = df_filtered, 
  method = "REML"
)
```

Comment: Is all your data from this one year? So one count per week and one sampling effort per week? Or are there different regions or years so that we have a number of observations with differing counts and sympling efforts per week? I think to judge on the "detections/total samplings" ratio you need to ask an onithologist whether it makes sense, that doubling the "samplings" will lead to twice as many detections.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have several samplings per week, but with strong variation (more samplings during the spring weeks for example). This is because the data I'm using is from a public database where citizens collect observations without following any specific protocol.

Just to give you an example, in the week 47, I have 48 detections of the studied bird, but more than 2500 non-detections. By contrast, in the week 25 I have 0 detections, and more than 3000 non-detections.

Comment: Please write a detailed description of the data sampling procedure. Judging from your last comment this appears to be a binomial process that should best be fit accordingly. Those observations with a lot of attempts to detect a bird should have a higher weight, such as in this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/487137/117812